# Spring @InitBinder on @RequestBody

Tags: spring

I'm trying to use the @InitBind annotation to map only certain fields on the object in the request body.

I have a spring controller defined in this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addAddress", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object addAddressToPerson(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse res,
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
        @RequestParam(value = "surname", required = false) String surname,
        @RequestBody personDTO personJson,BindingResult result) {
```

The client request will be a a json representing a personDTO, but I don't want that field except the address to be mapped in the object for security reasons.

The input will be something like:

```
{ "address":"123 Street","........}
```

The personDTO contains many fields, and since spring map all of them directly in a DTO, that can be a problem.

I've seen that a solution is to use a Binder to declase the allowed or Disallowed field, but if I check the personDTO inside the controller, other fields are populate (for example if pass "id":"1234").

Any Hints?

The binder code is the following:

```
    @InitBinder("orderJson")
protected void orderJsonBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.setAllowedFields(new String[]{"address"});
}
```

Am I missing something?

Best Regards,

Luca.

Answer (score 3):

But you are **not** binding request parameters to a model attribute bean, you are just asking spring to use an appropriate MessageConverter to convert the request body. As you say it is Json, you will use a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter (or MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter with Jackson 1.x). The Spring Reference Manual says for this converter :

*[This is an] HttpMessageConverter implementation that can read and write JSON using Jackson's ObjectMapper. JSON mapping can be customized as needed through the use of Jackson's provided annotations. When further control is needed, a custom ObjectMapper can be injected through the ObjectMapper property for cases where custom JSON serializers/deserializers need to be provided for specific types. By default this converter supports (application/json).*

`@InitBinder` can only configure binding of `@ModelAttribute` annotated parameters. It is useless here. If Jackson annotations are not enough, you will have to use a custom object mapper.

And I am surprised that you can use a `BindingResult` after a `@RequestBody` parameter, because the documentation says that it should follow a `@ModelAttribute` one.

Comment: Thank you Serge.
According to your hint I have to write a custom ObjectMapper for jackson (in my application spring use the JsonSerialize annotation on the class, so in the controller the json in automatically converted to a java object. The problem is that for the same class annotated with JsonSerialize, I need different behaviour for different method (for example in the addAddress I need only the address field, maybe in the addCredit card I'll nedd just the creditCart field. You know how I can write custom ObjectMapper for different Controller/RequestMapping?